# Outlook VBA - A startup macro that moves incoming undeliverable (NDR class) messages for multiple shared inboxes

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, visual-basic, shared-mailbox

I have a little experience in Java but barely any in Visual Basic. I need to create a macro for my work Outlook that has 4 inboxes in the profile. One is my name@abc.net, another is for marketing@abc.net, one for info, and one for monthlyStatements. I've seen on here a already a solution for NDR class messages that seems to work for some people ([Is it possible to set up rule in Outlook 2010 based on message class?](https://superuser.com/questions/665221/is-it-possible-to-set-up-rule-in-outlook-2010-based-on-message-class)). However, it does not work for me and my colleagues who share the same inboxes. Basically, we all are responsible for maintaining the 3 inboxes plus our own and we get a ton of Undeliverable replies. We would like to filter out the NDR class messages to a subfolder. Does anyone know of a way of modifying the solution in the link above to filter all inboxes to a subfolder called "NDRs" under the info inbox?

Answer (score 0):

Create a listener for each of the four inboxes.

You can test the subject for text unique to your non delivery item.

In ThisOutlookSession

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents defaultInboxItems As Items
Private WithEvents marketingItems As Items
Private WithEvents infoItems As Items
Private WithEvents monthlyStatementsItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Set defaultInboxItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
Set marketingItems = Session.folders("marketing@abc.net").folders("Inbox").Items
Set infoItems = Session.folders("info@abc.net").folders("Inbox").Items
Set monthlyStatementsItems = Session.folders("monthlyStatements@abc.net").folders("Inbox").Items
End Sub


Private Sub defaultInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim fldrS As folders
    Dim fldr As Folder

    Dim nonDeliverySubject As String
    Dim lenNonDeliverySubject As Long

    Debug.Print "Subject: " & Item.Subject

    ' If the start of subject of the non delivery message is "Mail System Error - Subject:"
    ' otherwise use what you receive

    nonDeliverySubject = "Mail System Error - Subject:"
    lenNonDeliverySubject = Len(nonDeliverySubject)

    Debug.Print "Left(UCase(Item.Subject), lenNonDeliverySubject): " & _
      Left(UCase(Item.Subject), lenNonDeliverySubject)

    ' It is safer to put UCase (or LCase) on both sides
    '  The unwary may type in the other case
    If Left(UCase(Item.Subject), lenNonDeliverySubject) = UCase(nonDeliverySubject) Then

        Set fldrS = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).folders

        ' Bypass error, for a specific reason, if NDR folder does not exist
        On Error Resume Next
        Set fldr = fldrS.Item("NDR")
        ' Return to normal error handling immediately
        On Error GoTo 0

        If fldr Is Nothing Then
            Set fldr = fldrS.Add("NDR")
        End If

        Item.Move fldr

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub marketingInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    ' repeat the code for defaultInboxItems_ItemAdd
    ' with one change
    Set fldrS = Session.folders("marketing@abc.net").folders("Inbox").folders
End Sub


Private Sub infoItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    ' repeat the code for defaultInboxItems_ItemAdd
    ' with one change
    Set fldrS = Session.folders("info@abc.net").folders("Inbox").folders
End Sub

Private Sub monthlyStatementsItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    ' repeat the code for defaultInboxItems_ItemAdd
    ' with one change
    Set fldrS = Session.folders("monthlyStatements@abc.net").folders("Inbox").folders
End Sub
```

The message class test for REPORT.IPM.NOTE.NDR in [Is it possible to set up rule in Outlook 2010 based on message class?](https://superuser.com/questions/665221/is-it-possible-to-set-up-rule-in-outlook-2010-based-on-message-class) may no longer be valid.

To check the message class of your non delivery item:

```
Debug.Print "UCase(Item.MessageClass): " & UCase(Item.MessageClass)
```